# Three.js rotating Earth with night light shader not working. Source code linked

Tags: three.js, webgl, shader

I would like to start off by saying that I asked this question previously but with multiple questions attached so instead I am opening a thread again but with only this.

I need to create a shader that mixes between earth in the day and earth at night (night lights in various cities). I've tried a technique that I saw on a previously answered question about this very topic but it didn't work out for me. I created the material for the shader and when I add it to the phong it changes the entire color of the earth to something green or purple (depending on where I add it).

Here is the link to my code. the area of interest is the earth.js

https://www.dropbox.com/s/6r8foqz25ont9b3/webgl-earth-master.zip?dl=0

Comment: A fiddle or other workable example of your javascript is more helpful than a .zip with all of your code